# MS Access Import UTF-8 file with BOM causes issue if the next char is double quote?

Tags: ms-access, utf-8, import, byte-order-mark

I found a strange issue, I'm wondering if anyone knows either why this happens or if it is a known bug (yes I Googled).

I have a database where I have to import CSV files using Access. I'm making some changes to the project to allow UNICODE characters to be into the database. There is some preprocessing involved in VBA by reading and writing using ADODB.Stream.

This ADODB.Stream is the only method of processing UNICODE files that I found to be of a useful level. However, I'm writing UTF-8 files with it and obviously, as it should, it writes a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the start of the file: `ï»¿`.

So far so good Microsoft, way to support standards! Now when this file is saved I want to import it using an ImportExportSpecification. I specifically specify Microsoft's Codepage 65001 which is what the rest of the world calls utf-8. Then try to import and no surprise it works.. *Until* your file starts with a double quote, then Access complains that the record 2 (2??) could not be parsed.

The unfortunate thing is that I cannot control the source of these files and I'm not involved in the actual imports, it's automated.. So now I either have to remove the BOM, which I don't really want to do.. because I need to read and write the entire file from to disk or in memory and these files are insanely huge.. Or remove the double quote, which is actually necessary for the headers of a file (that I can't control either).

**TL;DR:** It appears that if your files starts with `ï»¿"` you break Access's ImportExport module. Is it a bug, a "feature" or why the .. does it happen?

Ok, so I will remove the BOM, so Christmas doesn't have to start without me. **But** it's **not** a solution, it's a band aid. I would very much like to know how to fix this, it's itching me.. :)

Merry Christmas!

Comment: BOMs are for UTF-16. It is wrong and nonstandard to write BOMs to UTF-8 files.

Comment: Maybe the access import module reads the BOM, decides on UTF-16, and has a fallback to UTF-8 if the next 2 bytes are not a valid codepoint. This would explain why, with some files, if the next byte is a `"`, the codepoint of the `"` plus the next byte is valid, but in other cases, it's invalid, so the fallback to UTF-8 (which is wrong after a BOM in the first place) doesn't occur with the `"`.

Comment: Thanks Guntram, but I believe in this international world we should use a BOM, imagine you are in China and recieve a file with some text. With a BOM, you text looks like ``, while without it, it looks like:`ð£Ž`.

Comment: In reply to your second comment, you may be right, this sound plausible, what I will do is test if I can save and import UTF-16 instead, even if the files will grow it doesn't matter much it's only in an intermediate state.. Thanks, will let you know..

Comment: I agree that we should use unicode in an international world, which means we should use some kind of UTF-encoding. BOMs are needed with UTF-16 or UTF-32, but UTF-8 doesn't need it, since the bytes are always ordered the same. Even the official unicode FAQ (http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5) states that BOMs aren't needed, and may be harmful, with UTF-8.

Comment: I know what the UTF-8 specification says, I'm familiar with it. I  think it should just not be called BOM, Byte Order Mark, but still you need to know what type of contents a file has, therefore I think they are very useful. Anyway.. This if a bit off-topic we're now discussing how standards should be implemented...

Comment: What version of Access are you using? I just tried importing a CSV file with a BOM and a leading `"` into Access 2010 using the Import Wizard and it worked fine. However, the Code Page was `Unicode (UTF-8)`, not `65001`. If you are using `DoCmd.TransferText` from VBA code then show us what that statement actually looks like.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm You cite [http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html). Did you notice further down on that same page where it says: "A particular protocol (e.g. Microsoft conventions for .txt files) may require use of the BOM on certain Unicode data streams, such as files. When you need to conform to such a protocol, use a BOM."?

Comment: The problem is "Unicode data streams" - that may be UTF-32, UTF-16, or UTF-8. The first 2 of these have different formats depending on byte order, so they need the BOM, and you cannot read a BOM-less file of unknown origin. The 3rd one, UTF-8, does not have byte order differences, so there's just no reason to include it. A file starting in EF BB BF could still be an iso-8859-something file (not very likely), so there's no generic reason to include BOMs with UTF-8. Of course, a specific implementation is free to choose anything, even EBCDIC, but BOM on UTF-8 just causes more harm than it fixes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Guntram Blohm pointed out:

> Maybe the access import module reads the BOM, decides on UTF-16, and has a fallback to UTF-8 if the next 2 bytes are not a valid codepoint.
>   This seems to be the case, it may be a bug, it may be that UTF-8 with BOM was not implemented completely, I don't know.. If you do feel free to drop a comment, I'm still curious.

Anyway, there are 3 ways you can "solve" the issue:

1. Remove the BOM (rewriting the entire file, could be done in memory rather than reading & writing from disk) see here: http://axlr8r.blogspot.nl/2011/05/how-to-export-data-into-utf-8-without.html
2. Remove the double quote or place an extra character after the BOM if you can.
3. Save the file as UTF-16 which Access seems to have better support for. Compared to an ANSI file a UTF-16 file will be twice the size. Whereas UTF-8 would only add extra bytes per character when special characters are met. In my case the file is in an intermediary state, I'm not keeping it, after importing I delete the file. So I chose to save the file as UTF-16 and import it with Codepage 1200 (which is UTF-16 for the rest of the world).

Answer (score 1):

> It appears that if your files starts with ï»¿" you break Access's ImportExport module.

No, that is not true, at least for reasonably current versions of Access. Given the CSV file "bomTest.csv":

[image: bomTest.png]

and the Import Specification

[image: ImportSpec.png]

the following statement imports the file correctly in Access 2010

```vbs
DoCmd.TransferText _
        TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
        SpecificationName:="BomTest Import Specification", _
        TableName:="bomTest", _
        FileName:="C:\__tmp\bomTest.csv", _
        HasFieldNames:=True
```

### Edit re: comment

Having a BOM in your UTF-8 CSV file when using the `ImportExportSpecification` method is not necessarily a show-stopper, either. Using the exact same sample CSV file as above, the following code imports it without incident:

```vbs
Public Sub bomImportTest()
    Dim ies As ImportExportSpecification, ies_XML As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ies = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications("zzzTemp")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ies.Delete
    End If
    Set ies = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    ies_XML = ""
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "<ImportExportSpecification Path=""C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\bomTest.csv"" xmlns=""urn:www.microsoft.com/office/access/imexspec"">" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "      <ImportText TextFormat=""Delimited"" FirstRowHasNames=""true"" FieldDelimiter="","" TextDelimiter=""{DoubleQuote}"" CodePage=""65001"" Destination=""BomTest"" >" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "           <NumberFormat DecimalSymbol=""."" />" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "             <Columns PrimaryKey="""">" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "                        <Column Name=""Col1"" FieldName=""column 1"" Indexed=""NO"" SkipColumn=""false"" DataType=""Text"" Width=""14"" />" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "                        <Column Name=""Col2"" FieldName=""column 2"" Indexed=""NO"" SkipColumn=""false"" DataType=""Text"" Width=""14"" />" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "             </Columns>" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "   </ImportText>" & vbCrLf
    ies_XML = ies_XML & "</ImportExportSpecification>" & vbCrLf
    Set ies = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Add("zzzTemp", ies_XML)
    ies.Execute
    Debug.Print "Import complete."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't use TransferText. Dealing with huge files the newer ImportExportSpecification works a lot faster, plus I programmatically create the XML specifications. I did some testing adding the UTF-8 "BOM" and came to the conclusion that it - without exception, failed to load the data. For me the quickest fix was to use UTF-16 between certain stages of my import process.