# CSV export from php / Import to Access using VBA --- schema.ini CharacterSet issue

Tags: php, vba, csv, ms-access

I am currently working on a thing where I want to export various tables from a MySQL Database to csv files and it should then be possible to import those csv files into an Access database with VBA.

I managed to produce a download of a zip file that contains csv files and a schema.ini. For importing the csv files, I use roughly (loop is omitted for the sake of brevity) this code:

```
Sub ImportTableOne()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    frompart = "[Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & CurrentProject.Path & "\csvfiles\" & ";].[fileone.csv];"
    db.Execute _
    "SELECT * INTO tableone FROM" & frompart, dbFailOnError
    db.TableDefs.Refresh
    RefreshDatabaseWindow
End Sub
```

My problem is that I can either have `CharacterSet=ANSI` in my schema.ini which of course produces a result where for example `í` turns into `Ã­-`. Changing things in the schema.ini to `CharacterSet=UTF-8` will produce a run-time error 3000: reserved error (-5402).

I already tried to get the csv file to behave more UTF-8ish in php by adding a UTF-8 bom right after `fopen()` like so:

```
fputs($csvfile, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );
```

When I open the csv files in excel or notepad++, the charset seems to be ok. When having the UTF-8 bom in php and trying to import, the bom just ends up being part of the first column heading like so: `ï»¿columnheadingone`. That might not be very surprising for all I know about how the schema.ini works.

I would appreciate any hints as to how to resolve this.

Comment: Curious, why not use PHP to connect via ODBC/OLEDB to MS Access database and append data? Even more, why not connect MySQL linked tables to Access and migrate to local tables, avoiding csv conversion?

Comment: I don't know yet if the server that this will run, will have the drivers installed and I most definitely won't have permissions to install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Text ISAM" driver and its associated "schema.ini" file do not support UTF-8 files because they pre-date the Unicode era. The "Selecting a Character Set" section of the MSDN document

[Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx)

says

> You can select from two character sets: ANSI and OEM.

So, you will probably need to devise another way to import your data. If you want to use UTF-8 then you may be interested in a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20760571/2144390).

Comment: Thanks for that. BTW: I googled and tried to load this very page I don't know how many times and got nothing but anchors. So for everybody who reads this: Wait. You will get nothing but anchor icons for the better part of a minute and then eventually the content you are looking for.

For now I'll just go [iconv ()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php) before changing to most likely the XML approach that is linked here.